# What use instead of TreeView in qml?

Tags: qml, qtreeview, qt6

Since qt 6.0 TreeView is deprecated in QML. What can I use instead it? Or how can I use C++ QTreeView in QML. Or how realized my own TreeView?

Comment: Yes, that's weird but they removed `TreeView` from the 6.0.  
You can either use the commercial version from the market ([link](https://marketplace.qt.io/products/treeview)) or implement your own control ([example](https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/north-america/QtQuickTreeView.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I don't want to pay for this. In https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/north-america/QtQuickTreeView.pdf I can not find source code of TreeView.

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading you, that's just an example, a direction in which you should try to implement your own control.

Comment: Exactly, I've been working with Qt since it was called Trolltech and what is happening is very upsetting for me.

Comment: The direction of development Qt framework is going in a bad way. :/ As @folibis mentioned the only way is to write it on your own. You can't find the source of QTreeView from Qt5.*. Developing your own tree view shouldn't be so difficult because you can write the logic in cpp with QAbstracModel and base it on other visual components to show it.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин here you can find an implementation for the tree view: https://github.com/Daguerreo/QMLTreeView

Answer (score 3):

It seems that TreeView is back from Qt 6.3.0

See

- TreeView documentation: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtquick-treeview.html
- Qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61630

I haven´t tried it yet, though